# How to define a interface which doesn't have some property in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I want to write a interface called `ProptyDontHaveChildren` which doesn't have proterty called `children`

```
type ChildrenType = Array<number>
interface ProptyDontHaveChildren  {
    // doesn't have property called children
    [index: string]: string;
}
interface WithChildren {
    children: ChildrenType 
}
type IntersectionType = ProptyDontHaveChildren & WithChildren;

function createElement(type: string, props: ProptyDontHaveChildren, ...children: ChildrenType ) {
    const newProps:IntersectionType = { children: children, ...props }
    //TODO ...
}
```

How to define a interface which doesn't have some property in TypeScript?

Comment: Can't; How `delete props['children']` before creating newProps or even simply: `newProps = { ... props}; newProps.children = children` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are quite a few problems here.  Be warned:

---

You could make `children` an optional property of type `never` or `undefined` in `ProptyDontHaveChildren` (it's important that the property be optional):

```
type ChildrenType = Array<number>
interface ProptyDontHaveChildren  {
    [index: string]: string;
    children?: never; // note the ?
}
```

That guarantees that `ProptyDontHaveChildren` can only be created from something with a missing or undefined `children` property.

---

But now the intersection `IntersectionType` will not be what you want: it also cannot have `children` because the intersection demands that `children` be both of type `undefined` and of type `ChildrenType`, which can't happen:

```
let oops: IntersectionType = { children: [1, 2, 3] } // error
```

So the best thing to do would be to define `ProptyDontHaveChildren` as the intersection of a base `Propty` type and a `WithoutChildren` type, so that you can then define `ProptyHaveChildren` (what you wanted `IntersectionType` to be) as the intersection of `Propty` and `WithChildren`.  Like this:

```
interface Propty  {
    [index: string]: string;
}
interface WithoutChildren {
    children?: never
}
interface WithChildren {
    children: ChildrenType 
}
type ProptyDontHaveChildren = Propty & WithoutChildren
type ProptyHaveChildren = Propty & WithChildren
```

But there's still a problem.  The `ProptyHaveChildren` type still can't have a property of type `children`, because the index signature requires that every property, *including `children`*, be of type `string`.  So `children` must be both a `string` and an array of `number`, which can't happen:

```
const proptyHaveChildren: ProptyHaveChildren = { 
  a: "a", 
  children: [1, 2, 3] 
}; // error!

function createElement(type: string, props: ProptyDontHaveChildren, ...children: ChildrenType) {
    // error!
    const newProps:ProptyHaveChildren = { children: children, ...props }
}
```

---

From here I'm not sure how you want to proceed.  TypeScript lacks [subtraction types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4183), which is what you'd need to say that the index signature should refer to every `string` key *except* `"children"`.  You could open up the `Propty` type so that every property is either a `string` or an array of `number`s:

```
interface Propty  {
    [index: string]: string | ChildrenType;
}

function createElement(type: string, props: ProptyDontHaveChildren, ...children: ChildrenType) {
    // no error
    const newProps:ProptyHaveChildren = { children: children, ...props }
}
```

That works, but now every property will accept an array of `numbers`:

```
const proptyHaveChildren: ProptyHaveChildren = { 
  a: [1, 2, 3], 
  children: [1, 2, 3] 
}; // no error!
```

That's probably not what you want.

---

At this point I notice I'm fighting with TypeScript to force it to understand your interface.  Maybe the best thing to do is to change your representation of `Propty` so that it contains two properties: a `props` property to hold all those `string` properties, and `children`:

```
type ChildrenType = Array<number>

interface Propty {
  props: { [index: string]: string }
}
interface WithoutChildren {
  children?: never
}
interface WithChildren {
  children: ChildrenType
}
type ProptyDontHaveChildren = Propty & WithoutChildren
type ProptyHaveChildren = Propty & WithChildren

const proptyHaveChildren: ProptyHaveChildren = { props: { a: "a" }, children: [1, 2, 3] }; // works

function createElement(type: string, props: ProptyDontHaveChildren, ...children: ChildrenType) {  
  const newProps: ProptyHaveChildren = { children: children, props: props.props } // works
}
```

Now TypeScript understands, and everything works... at the expense of pulling your type apart into multiple sub-properties.  You might prefer your original structure.  It's up to you whether you prefer it enough to deal with the issues above.

---

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the type [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never) to indicate that `children` should not exist on `ProptyDontHaveChildren`:

```
type ChildrenType = Array<number>
interface ProptyDontHaveChildren  {
    [index: string]: string;
    children: never;
}
interface WithChildren {
    children: ChildrenType 
}
type IntersectionType = ProptyDontHaveChildren & WithChildren;

function createElement(type: string, props: ProptyDontHaveChildren, ...children: ChildrenType) {
    // OK. No error
    const newProps:IntersectionType = { children: children, ...props }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately there are problems with this solution, which become apparent when you try to create instances of the types above.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46322516/2887218) for more information.